# React set route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Just started with React and wanted to define routes for my app. I understood the general concept of how react defines routes but my script that I basically wrote and don't understand a lot is slightly different from the examples found on youtube regarding routers. Can anyone help me?

App.js

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Header from  "./layout/Header";
import Dashboard from  "./users/Dashboard";
import Users from  "./users/Users";

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from '../store';

import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Fragment>
                    <Header />
                    <div className="container">
                        <Dashboard />
                    </div>
                </Fragment> 
            </Provider>     
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Specify the lines that you don't understand

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: I understand this code and it works and I can see the results at localhost:8000 but I want to define a new router for this example localhost:8000/users

Answer (score 0):

> You need to read the documentation: [Documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)

But for start let me show you a simple usage:

First wrap your code with `Router` component:

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
              <Router>
                <Fragment>
                    <Header />
                    <div className="container">
                        <Dashboard />
                    </div>
                </Fragment> 
              </Router>
            </Provider>     
        );
    }
}
```

Then you can specify which component has to be shown when some specific url is reached. Like below:

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
              <Router>
                <Fragment>
                    <div className="container">
                        <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
                    </div>
                </Fragment> 
              </Router>
            </Provider>     
        );
    }
}
```

Using the above code will render the `Header` always. And it will render `Dashboard` component only when you are on the page with the `/dashboard` in the url.

Comment: I'm getting an error app is declared twice, tried to change the name of the one bellow but I'm not getting any results